# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

Tags: postgresql, dbunit

I am trying to use dbunit-express in my java project to create some tables and functions on postgress in Junit tests.

I use this driver :

```
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
```

The java class...

```
@Rule 
public EmbeddedDbTesterRule testDb = new EmbeddedDbTesterRule(); // with this you don't neet to call onSetup

@Test
public void testIt() throws Exception {

    try {
        DatabaseCreator databaseCreator = new DatabaseCreator();
        databaseCreator.setDdlFile("HistoryTables.ddl");
        databaseCreator.doCreateDbSchemaFromDdl(testDb.getSqlConnection());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I get this error...

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$

The function looks like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION product_history()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product_history (id, product_id, edit_ts, name, print_provider_id,     description)
    VALUES (nextval('product_history_sequence'), OLD.id, now(), OLD.name,     OLD.print_provider_id, OLD.description);
RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The create works fine in PGAdmin 1.14.3 and in DBVisualizer 9.0.8

Comment: Sounds like something is changing your code before it hits the backend. Can you have a look in your postgresql logs at the error it is reporting depeninding on your configuration it will include the query it actually received so we could see what has changed. As a work around you could try converting the dollar quoted string to a normal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `create function` code included in `HistoryTables.ddl`? If yes the error might be caused by a limitation of `DatabaseCreator`. It splits statements read from the ddl file at `;` (see [line 127 of the source code](https://github.com/jakubholynet/dbunit-express/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jakubholy/dbunitexpress/DatabaseCreator.java). The function is therefore splitted into multiple statements disturbing the syntax.

Try to move the function code into an extra file and send this file as one statement to your server.

Comment: Ya that is the problem. I forked the project and changed the delimiter  to a hash and put a hash in the file.. and it worked